# Inheriting from different assembly

Tags: c#, oop

I've added reference of `ProjectA` in `ProjectB` and inherit the `Class1` in `Class2`. Here I am able to access both methods (`Sample1` and `Sample2`) in `Class2`.

But if I added reference of `ProjectB` in `ProjectC` and try to access `Sample1` it gives compile time error.

My doubt: if I inherit `ProjectA.Class1` in `ProjectB.Class2`, which means copy of methods in `Class1` should be in `Class2`, then why `Sample1` method is not available in `ProjectC.Class3` even if I added reference to `ProjectB`?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ProjectA
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void Sample1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ProjectA;

namespace ProjectB
{
    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        public void Sample2()
        {
            Class2 obj = new Class2();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ProjectB;

namespace ProjectC
{
    public class Class3 
    {
        public void Sample2()
        {
            Class2 obj = new Class2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Inheritance doesn't "copy the methods".  If Project C needs to use code that's in Project A then Project C will need a reference to Project A.

Comment: Thanks David but i dont want to access the methods in ProjectA but if i compile the ProjectC means the following error occuring :The type 'ProjectA.Class1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ProjectA,

Comment: iam not accessing the methods from ProjectA . but i want to know why the error is occur in compile time when i create object for the Class2 kindly clarify my doubt.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Even if you're not calling a method however, part of the physical construct of `ClassB` comes from Project A.  So you'll still need that reference in order to create an instance of `ClassB`.

Comment: Now iam clear Thanks David .

Answer (score 1):

Inside the last `ProjectC` assembly you have `Class2 obj = new Class2();`. That means that the assembly of `Class2` ***and*** the assemblies of all the (direct and indirect) base classes of `Class2`, including the assembly of `Class1`, needs to be referenced from `ProjectC`.

Instances of `Class2`, like `obj`, possess both the methods inherited from the base class, like `Sample1`, and the methods declared directly in `Class2` (`Sample2`), but I doubt that is relevant to your "problem".

---

Addition: Here is an example with classes from the BCL. Create a new empty project with Visual Studio (or whatever IDE). Per default the new project will reference the BCL assembly `System.dll`, but not the BCL assembly `System.Configuration.dll`. Then use this program:

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace N
{
  static class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      new UriSection();
    }
  }
}
```

The compiler will emit **error CS0012: The type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.** The reason is clearly that the [`System.Configuration.UriSection` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.urisection.aspx) is declared in an assembly you do refer, while its direct base class [`System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationsection.aspx) (mentioned in the error text) is defined in an assembly you don't use.

The assembly of `N.Program` needs to reference both assemblies (and implicitly `mscorlib.dll`, the assembly of class `System.Object`).

Comment: Thanks Jeppe.. nice example now i understood

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's simple - ProjectA is *not* linked into ProjectB - it's only referenced. The same way, `Class2` doesn't have an implementation of `Sample1` at all, that's implemented in `Class1` only. If you had overriden the method in `Class2`, this would change. But again, of course, if you'd call the base method from there, it would again be referencing the method in `Class1`, not copying it.

So when you're referencing ProjectB, you also need to reference ProjectA. Everything is dynamically linked in .NET (unless you add a separate merging step, which is usually not the best idea).